# Error 10054: Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал подключение

Tags: база-данных, sql-server

Только что установила MS SQL 2017 на linux сервер, локально удаётся подключиться через

**$ sqsh -S localhost -U sa**

А вот с удалённым подключением проблема, не хочет подключаться и всё тут. Может чего не настроено у него? Вот такую ошибку выдаёт:

Подключение к серверу успешно установлено, но затем произошла ошибка при входе. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - Удаленный хост принудительно разорвал существующее подключение.) (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

Какие могут быть решения проблемы? Куда смотреть? По установке MS SQL 2017 на linux в сети вообще информации очень мало.

```
root@vps188507:~# cat /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2018-06-07 14:08:50.38 Server      Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM-CU7) (KB4229789) - 14.0.3026.27 (X64)
        May 10 2018 12:38:11
        Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation
        Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie))
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      UTC adjustment: -4:00
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      (c) Microsoft Corporation.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      All rights reserved.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      Server process ID is 4124.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      Logging SQL Server messages in file '/var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog'.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.39 Server      Registry startup parameters:
         -d /var/opt/mssql/data/master.mdf
         -l /var/opt/mssql/data/mastlog.ldf
         -e /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog
2018-06-07 14:08:50.40 Server      SQL Server detected 2 sockets with 1 cores per socket and 1 logical processors per socket, 2 total logical processors; using 2 logical processors based on SQL Server licensing. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.40 Server      SQL Server is starting at normal priority base (=7). This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.40 Server      Detected 6251 MB of RAM. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.40 Server      Using conventional memory in the memory manager.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.60 Server      Buffer pool extension is already disabled. No action is necessary.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.78 Server      InitializeExternalUserGroupSid failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.78 Server      Implied authentication manager initialization failed. Implied authentication will be disabled.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.80 Server      Successfully initialized the TLS configuration. Allowed TLS protocol versions are ['1.0 1.1 1.2']. Allowed TLS ciphers are ['ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:!DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:!DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA'].
2018-06-07 14:08:50.85 Server      The maximum number of dedicated administrator connections for this instance is '1'
2018-06-07 14:08:50.85 Server      Node configuration: node 0: CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0 Active CPU mask: 0x0000000000000003:0. This message provides a description of the NUMA configuration for this computer. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.88 Server      Using dynamic lock allocation.  Initial allocation of 2500 Lock blocks and 5000 Lock Owner blocks per node.  This is an informational message only.  No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.90 Server      In-Memory OLTP initialized on lowend machine.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.97 Server      Database Instant File Initialization: enabled. For security and performance considerations see the topic 'Database Instant File Initialization' in SQL Server Books Online. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:50.99 Server      Query Store settings initialized with enabled = 1,
2018-06-07 14:08:51.01 spid6s      Starting up database 'master'.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.01 Server      Software Usage Metrics is disabled.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.35 spid6s      Resource governor reconfiguration succeeded.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.35 spid6s      SQL Server Audit is starting the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.35 spid6s      SQL Server Audit has started the audits. This is an informational message. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.46 spid6s      SQL Trace ID 1 was started by login "sa".
2018-06-07 14:08:51.50 spid6s      Server name is 'vps188507'. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.56 spid9s      Starting up database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.56 spid22s     Always On: The availability replica manager is starting. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.56 spid22s     Always On: The availability replica manager is waiting for the instance of SQL Server to allow client connections. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.57 spid6s      Starting up database 'msdb'.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.57 spid9s      The resource database build version is 14.00.3026. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.60 spid9s      Starting up database 'model'.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.89 spid9s      Polybase feature disabled.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.89 spid9s      Clearing tempdb database.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.89 spid19s     A self-generated certificate was successfully loaded for encryption.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.90 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv6> 1433].
2018-06-07 14:08:51.90 spid19s     Server is listening on [ 'any' <ipv4> 1433].
2018-06-07 14:08:51.90 Server      Server is listening on [ ::1 <ipv6> 1434].
2018-06-07 14:08:51.90 Server      Server is listening on [ 127.0.0.1 <ipv4> 1434].
2018-06-07 14:08:51.91 Server      Dedicated admin connection support was established for listening locally on port 1434.
2018-06-07 14:08:51.92 spid19s     SQL Server is now ready for client connections. This is an informational message; no user action is required.
2018-06-07 14:08:52.39 spid9s      Starting up database 'tempdb'.
2018-06-07 14:08:52.60 spid9s      The tempdb database has 1 data file(s).
2018-06-07 14:08:52.60 spid24s     The Service Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2018-06-07 14:08:52.61 spid24s     The Database Mirroring endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.
2018-06-07 14:08:52.62 spid24s     Service Broker manager has started.
2018-06-07 14:08:52.65 spid6s      Recovery is complete. This is an informational message only. No user action is required.
```

Comment: DBCC TRACEON(4029,-1); Потом в логе сервера посмотрите подробности ошибки/ошибок, лог здесь: /var/opt/mssql/log/errorlog

Comment: всё решилось установкой на Ubuntu 16.04 - заработало тут же сразу после установки. Всем спасибо.